# Configuration values are not loaded when testing private method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a class:

```
    @Service
    public class MyService{
        @Value("${some.value}")
        private String someValue;

        private String someMethod(String inputString){
           return inputString == null || inputString.isEmpty() ? someValue : inputString;
        } 
    }
```

In the properties file the some.value defined like this:

```
some.value=SomeValue
```

Then I am trying to test the someMethod using ReflectionTestUtils:

```
public class MyTest{

   @Value("${some.value}")
   private String someValue;

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   @Test
   public void testSomeMethod() {
       Assert.assertEquals(someValue, ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(myService, "someMethod", ""));
   }
}
```

And I get the following error:

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected :SomeValue Actual   :null

When debugging I see that inside the service i am testing - configuration values are null.

It is even more strange (to me :) ) that if I change someMethod from private to public everything works well.

Comment: Let me guess this isn't the actual code you are testing but a simplified version and in your real application you have code that needs/requires AOP like transactions, security etc.

Comment: It is a simplified version. Since there are many other things in the project, I thought aren't relevant, Is there anything specific you need to know?

Comment: Yes if you use AOP or not (although I suspect I already know the answer). I suspect that the sample you posted here (without AOP) willl just work, however as soon as you add AOP in the mix it (appears) not to work.

Answer (score 2):

add  this annotation in your class :

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @PropertySource("classpath:name-file.properties ")
```

and in your package resources for test add file :

```
src/test/resources/name-file.properties
```

Comment: It is not working, my properties file is already under src/test/resources. The thing is that it is not working only when testing private methods.

Comment: try this system.getProperty("keyforproperties");